# The DataTemplate in HubSection doesn't get full height

Tags: windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I have the following code:

```
<HubSection x:Name="modules_section" ...>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        ..................................
```

How can I get the StackPanel to take the full height of the HubSection?

VerticalAlignment="Stretch" doesn't do the job.

I also tried to use binding via

```
<StackPanel Height={Binding ElementName=modules_section, Path=ActualHeight}" ...>
```

but the Actualheight of the hub section seems to be 0 (I also tried to set it in code-behind and debugged to see the value).

Comment: I'm setting up my windows 8.1 environment to reproduce the issue, could you tell me the code around the `HubSection`?

Answer (score 8):

A `<StackPanel>` is as large as the content within it, but in general, to make the items within a `<HubSection>` as tall as the remainingspace in the section it is as simple as setting the `VerticalContentAlignment` on the section, i.e:

```
<HubSection VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <DataTemplate>
        <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollMode="..." VerticalScrollMode="...">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                ...
```

In this case, I'm wrapping my `<StackPanel>` in a `<ScrollViewer>` to cope with when the case with when there is enough data to need to scroll

Comment: This solves the same problem I have with a Windows Store app.  It should be accepted as the answer unless the the author of the question has found it not working for his case.

Comment: @RowlandShaw For some reason, this didn't work in my case... Could you take alook at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28760148/vertical-scrolling-for-hubsection-content, please? Thank you in advance

Comment: @VasileF You don't appear to be setting `VerticalContentAlignment` on your `HubSection`s?

Comment: @RowlandShaw, it is true the code I presented doesn't have VerticalContentAlignment on the HubSection. I tried that and also wrap the textblock in a scrollviewer but with no success... If you have any further ideas, please answer on the question I have posted. Sorry for the interference on this post.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use all the height and you don't want to user the Hub.Header property 
you have this solution

In the resources of the page you write a Custom Style for the HubSection:

```
<Style x:Key="Prova" TargetType="HubSection">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="HubSection">
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <Border.Resources>
                            <ControlTemplate x:Key="HeaderButtonTemplate" TargetType="Button">
                                <Grid Background="Transparent">
                                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource HubSectionHeaderPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="IsHeaderInteractiveMarker">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource HubSectionHeaderPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource HubSectionHeaderPressedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="IsHeaderInteractiveMarker">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource HubSectionHeaderPressedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="IsHeaderInteractiveMarker">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualWhite"/>
                                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualBlack"/>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused"/>
                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="IsHeaderInteractiveStates">
                                            <VisualState x:Name="HeaderInteractive">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="IsHeaderInteractiveMarker">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="HeaderNonInteractive"/>
                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FlowDirectionStates">
                                            <VisualState x:Name="LeftToRight"/>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="RightToLeft">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Text" Storyboard.TargetName="IsHeaderInteractiveMarker">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="  &#xE26C;"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" OpticalMarginAlignment="TrimSideBearings" TextLineBounds="Tight" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                        <TextBlock x:Name="IsHeaderInteractiveMarker" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}" OpticalMarginAlignment="TrimSideBearings" TextLineBounds="Tight" Text=" &#xE26B;" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualWhite" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="-5" Opacity="0" StrokeDashOffset="1.5" StrokeEndLineCap="Square" Stroke="{ThemeResource FocusVisualWhiteStrokeThemeBrush}" StrokeDashArray="1,1"/>
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualBlack" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="-5" Opacity="0" StrokeDashOffset="0.5" StrokeEndLineCap="Square" Stroke="{ThemeResource FocusVisualBlackStrokeThemeBrush}" StrokeDashArray="1,1"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Border.Resources>
                        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <!--<Rectangle x:Name="HubHeaderPlaceholder" Grid.Row="0"/>-->
                            <!--<Button x:Name="HeaderButton" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" FontWeight="{ThemeResource HubSectionHeaderThemeFontWeight}" FontSize="{ThemeResource HubSectionHeaderThemeFontSize}" Margin="{ThemeResource HubSectionHeaderThemeMargin}" Grid.Row="1" Template="{StaticResource HeaderButtonTemplate}"/>-->
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Grid.Row="2"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

in your HubSection then you will have

```
<HubSection x:Uid="Section1Header" Style="{StaticResource Prova}">
```

That's all

Comment: What about when you do still want the headers? In my case, I'm seeing a ScrollViewer grow taller than the available space

Comment: you can use RowSpan and uncomment the header part